# modify manifest files of other android applications

Tags: android, security

im trying to develop a android application locker.is they anyway i can open and modify other applications manifest files and make it launch my activity first before the actual application activity.
Ive developed my locking system.i only need to actually lock and application.

Comment: can you able to give more explanation about what your have tried and what result you are expecting ?

Comment: i want to lock any android application using the app im developing.im currently developing a application  locker which is based on click cued points(CCP).so now for example suppose i wish to lock 'instagram' on my android phone.i want it to launch my CCP app rather than directly opening the instagram homepage.only if the user passes my security check he should be allowed to access instagram.

Comment: you can do this by reading the system log, i remember one svn/git tutorial i had come across before a long time on the same you are looking for.if i got the link again i will surly share with you. mean time please search for app-locker tutorial in google.

Comment: look this app, the code link  is also given below by the developer https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gueei.applocker

Comment: i would not like anyone coming n modifying my app manifest file just because its an app locker .. :)..

Comment: @Sreekanthss you cannot read system logs in recent versions

Comment: yes google make some changes, @ChrisStratton thank you for correcting me .but the above link worked for till jellybean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible. And you shouldn't be trying to do that, it'd be a huge breach in security. On a real note, you should create a service which runs constantly and listens  for when a specific application would be launched. And when it is launched, your application would be shown first. Also your "locking system" should be what I described above, if it's not,I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: thanks.can you tell me how would one go about developing this service as i am not very familiar with the android system and this is my college project

Comment: Have a look at this sample app. https://code.google.com/p/applocker/. It'll guide you as to what to do.

Comment: is it possible to replace the default lock screen activity with my lock screen activity?

Comment: It is if the user permits. Not otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the Google Play Terms of service before trying to modify manifest files of other Apps :

http://play.google.com/intl/en_in/about/android-developer-policies.html